Point shapefile without spatial reference
I have a few point shapefiles that I want to combine. Two of them do not have a spatial reference. No matter what I do to try to add a spatial reference or change the shapefile, the points disappear. What do I do? I didn't create these shapes, but they have been added to for years, and there are thousands of points. The only thing I can think of is to create a new shapefile with a reference and recreate it point by point. When I tried to define the projection, the attributes stayed intact, but the points themselves disappeared.

If the points in the two shapefiles disappeared when you gave them a projection definition, then you gave them the wrong one.  Try different projection definitions until they stay in place.  It is possible they were created with no coordinate system, or you never find the correct one.  You could try to zoom out to all layers, select the points of one of the shapefile in an edit session and move them to the correct position as best as possible.  Then give them the map projection.  You also can use the spatial adjustment toolbar.  Reminder, giving a projection definition is not reprojection.

This question is similar to: Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap in ArcMap but do not?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Note: This is the canonical ArcGIS Answer for the most frequent GIS SE question. The rule is: If changing the projection makes it move, you assigned the wrong projection.

If you able to identify approximate location for at least one 'wrong' point relative to correct point it is doable. Algorithm will shuffle through list of projections available in Arc and produce likely candidate (s). I can dig an old script

Even though this is really a duplicate: post the extent or at least a sample point's coordinates, plus a general location where the point/extent should be (city, county, state, etc.). Someone may be able to help.

@GraceIS, share more details of the or shapefile or the shapefile itself and the expected location, and that can help someone narrow down this issue.

Each of the shapefiles had coordinates as attributes. When I went to Add by XY, they appeared as they should. I then changed the coordinate system to match the other files and merge them.
